# python: Display multi seaborn distribution plot in a single window

Tags: python, seaborn

I was trying to plot the seaborn distribution plot for a list of columns.

```
for i in ['age', 'trestbps', 'chol','thalach','oldpeak', 'ca']:
    sns.distplot(Data_heart_copy[i])
```

[The output with above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdY0W.png)

However, what I wanted to display is distplot for all the above columns in a single window with a compact command

The output that I am looking for looks like this
[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNtZ9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use subplot to put plots side by side:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i, col in enumerate(['age', 'trestbps', 'chol','thalach','oldpeak', 'ca']):
    plt.subplot(2,3,i+1)
    sns.distplot(Data_heart_copy[col])
```

`plt.subplot(nrow, ncol, item)` takes 3 input arguments: number of rows in the grid, number of columns, and the plot index (starting from 1 to nrow x ncol)